# Cannot find -lCommunication collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c

I do not know `gcc` and `c` well. In my `/home/pi/Desktop/intern/adis16227_generic` directory I have following 5 files.

```
ADIS16227.c  
ADIS16227.h  
Communication.c  
Communication.h  
main.c
```

**main.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "Communication.h"  // Communication definitions.

int main() {
    printf("hello!!\n");
    unsigned char status = 0;
    status = SPI_Init(0, 1000000, 1, 1);
    printf("%u", status);
    return 0;
}
```

**Run command:**

```
$ sudo gcc -L /home/pi/Desktop/intern/adis16227_generic main.c -lCommunication
```

**Error:**

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCommunication
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Question:**

What I am missing here?

What do I need to run the code?

Comment: As soon as you have included your Communication library at `#include "Communication.h" ` you have already loaded the library, the -lLibrary_name option is to load shared libraries.

Comment: no, not necessarily shared. compiling doesn't load the library either. That's nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

those options:

```
-L /home/pi/Desktop/intern/adis16227_generic -lCommunication
```

suggest that the linker should find `libCommunication.a` (or `.so`) in the `/home/pi/Desktop/intern/adis16227_generic` directory.

But there are only sources in this directory. The linker won't build the sources of your "Communication" library for you.

So you could build the library and link with it:

```
gcc -c ADIS16227.c Communication.c
ar r libCommunication.a ADIS16227.o Communication.o
```

but maybe the fastest & quickest way to achieve a successful build would be:

```
sudo gcc -o main *.c
```

so it compiles all the files of the directory into the executable called `main`

Of course, it makes compilation times longer, but maybe it's not noticeable.

Answer (score 3):

`-l` is for libraries, and you never built a library from your `Communication.c`. The simplest solution is just add `Communication.c` to your compiler command line.

---

For larger projects, compile each translation unit separately with the `-c` switch like this:

```
gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -omain.o main.c
gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -oCommunication.o Communication.c
```

and so on ... (as a suggestion, I added some common *warning options* here, they help you spot errors)

The resulting `.o` files are *object code*. That's already compiled machine code, but with meta-information needed for a linker to link it with other object code into a complete executable.

Then link them all with one command:

```
gcc -oprogram main.o Communication.o
```

---

If you actually **want** a library from -- say -- `Communication.c` and `ADIS16227.c`, you could compile both to *object code*:

```
gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -oCommunication.o Communication.c
gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic --oADIS16227.o ADIS16227.c
```

and then use `ar` to create a **static library** from them:

```
ar rcs libCommunication.a Communication.o ADIS16227.o
```

Then your initial compiler command would work (with the `-lCommunication` switch).

---

Final piece of advice: **Never** compile as root. This is completely unnecessary. So remove your `sudo` here.

Answer (score 1):

First move into the `/home/pi/Desktop/intern/adis16227_generic` directory:

```
cd /home/pi/Desktop/intern/adis16227_generic
```

Then, compile the source:

```
gcc ADIS16227.c Communication.c main.c -I .
```

You can now run your compiled program (called by default `a.out`):

```
./a.out
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to compile separatedly files and then compile main with related obj file.

```
gcc -c Communication.c Communication.h
gcc main.c Communication.o -o main
```